# Get request to json api, I get as error: redirect was called multiple times. I am not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, request

From an external app, I make a get request to an api:

```
  def index
    user_id = params["user_id"].to_i
    api_url = "#{Rails.configuration.zaina_platform_path}/api/v1/users/#{user_id}/projects.json" 
    html_file = open(api_url).read

    @deal_rooms = JSON.parse(html_file)
  end
```

I end up in the right method (end point of my api) and I successfully filter the array:

```
  def filter
    user_id = params["user_id"].to_i
    guest_user = User.find(user_id)
    all_projects = policy_scope(Project)

    @user_projects = user_projects(all_projects, guest_user)
  end
```

Then, I create the JSON response in the view:

```
# app/views/api/v1/projects/filter.json.jbuilder
json.array! @user_projects do |project|
  json.extract! project, :id, :name, :description
end
```

When I make the request, unfortunately, I get following error message:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):

app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb:30:in `internal_server_error'
```

I can not figure out why, I am not redirecting. The point is, show and index work, filter, which is not a rails method, it does not work. Any ideas?

The complete log error is as follows:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/users/1/projects.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-19 22:28:13 +0200
Processing by Api::V1::ProjectsController#filter as JSON
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
  ProjectMember Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "project_members".* FROM 
  CACHE EntrepreneurProfile Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entrepreneur_profiles".* FROM "entrepreneur_profiles" WHERE "entrepreneur_profiles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering api/v1/projects/filter.json.jbuilder
  Rendered api/v1/projects/filter.json.jbuilder (0.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 152ms (Views: 4.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)



AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):

app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb:30:in `internal_server_error'
```

and the routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }
  # devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      get "users/:user_id/projects", to: "projects#filter"

      resources :projects, only: [ :show, :index ]
      # get "/api/v1/projects/"
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In my filter method I am using:

```
all_projects = policy_scope(Project)
```

So at the end it's like the index method, I need to very the policy scope and not the method verify_authorized from pundit

```
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: [:index, :filter] ###
```

It was a pundit issue. The error was totally misleading, it was not a redirect issue.

I found it checking the exception in my base_controller.rb

```
  def internal_server_error(exception)
    if Rails.env.development?
      response = { type: exception.class.to_s, message: exception.message, backtrace: exception.backtrace }
    else
      response = { error: "Internal Server Error" }
    end
    render json: response, status: :internal_server_error
  end
```

Here I could read the real error, problem with the Authentication, and not with the redirect.